# How do I add attribute validation to Realm models?

Tags: swift, realm

In a swift IOS app I have a Realm Model like this:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object {
  dynamic var name = ""

  let prices = List<Price>()
}
```

This lets me save an instance of Item with an empty String as a name:

```
let newItem = Item()
newItem.name = ""  //or not set the attribute at all
let realm = Realm()
realm.write {
  realm.add(newItem)
}
```

How can I setup simple (and more complex) attribute validation?

The name String is supplied from an UITextField. Do I do validate the user input in the ViewController responsible here, or is there a way to do this on the Realm Model, like the rails developer in me wants to do?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers,
nc

Answer (score 2):

Realm currently does not support validation beyond uniqueness for primary keys, but you can follow https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1769 for further updates!